# (Parent) theme Is Not Showing In Theme Selection Panel and Therefore Breaks Child Theme

Tags: theme-development, themes, child-theme, theme-customizer

I'm a WordPress developer but this one has left me scratching my head...

I've got a parent theme and a child theme.

Works great on my local machine, and was working great on my live server.

However on the live server, if I go to the Themes page, or Customizer panel, then the site resets to the default WordPress 2019 theme.

Also, on the Themes page, it doesn't show my parent theme but does should my child theme.

The files are definitely there. One cause I'm looking at them, and two because the child-theme does work, up until I go to customize something when it breaks.

I think I'm going to spin up a fresh server later and see if that makes a difference, but was hoping someone even smarter than I can save me some time and let me know what could be causing this weird issue.

Comment: did you confirm style.css file and also check in your database.

Comment: Yes. The parent style.css is there. What do you mean, check your database?

Comment: Maybe there was cache issue therefore check in database  which theme is activated and child theme. https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-change-wordpress-theme-using-phpmyadmin/